# I'm fetching data from API using Axios and getting error Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError

Tags: reactjs, axios

when I am fetching data from api and it is completely working but throwing this error :

```
AxiosError

code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}

message: "Request failed with status code 404"

request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}

response: {data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta char…re>Cannot GET /discover/tv</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}

stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41933:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40631:66)"
```

## my Row.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
function Row({ title, fetchUrl }) {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
            console.log(request);
            return request;
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Row
```

## axios.js file

```
import axios from "axios";
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
});
export default instance;
```

Comment: You probably need and API key from TMDB to access these endpoints. Try reading docs here: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies

Comment: You appear to be importing `axios` from the Axios library rather than your specific instance which has been configured with a baseURL. You probably meant `import axios from './axios'` or something similar with a relative path. **This can be closed as a TYPO**

Comment: Ya, I already find the solution thanks for your help and your answer is correct I did a mistake in importing the file but I corrected this mistake, and thank you for answering.